# How to delete all rows under a special row in pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to delete all the rows under the row with one column "Exercises" in pandas (Python)?

Data:

```
2021.08.16 19:37:15 146242975   XAUEUR  buy 0.02    1 517.04    1 517.19    1 519.54    2021.08.16 20:38:30 1 517.15    - 0.12  0.00     0.22
2021.08.16 19:37:15 146242976   XAUEUR  buy 0.02    1 517.04    1 517.19    1 522.04    2021.08.16 20:38:30 1 517.15    - 0.12  0.00     0.22
Exercises
2021.08.16 01:02:11 146037881   XAUUSD  buy 0.18 / 0.18 market  1 777.72    1 781.47    2021.08.16 01:02:11 filled      TP1
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1,2,3,4,'Excercises',6,7,8]})
#First find the row index by filtering the column value
my_index = df.index[df['num'] == 'Exercises'].tolist()[0] # as you my find multiple match, take the first index found by [0]
#my_index  = 4
#Then slice the Dataframe and take values into new df
df_new = df[:my_index] # or if you want to exclude that row , then add +1 to my_index
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the loc function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['2021.08.16 19:37:15 146242975','2021.08.16 19:37:15 146242976','Exercises','2021.08.16 01:02:11 146037881'],'values':['a','b','c','d']})
df2 = df.set_index('col')
df2.loc[:'Exercises'][:-1].reset_index()
```